# Inequalities having inconsistent InputForm

Tags: output-formatting, inequalities

I'm having a tough time dealing with inequalities.

`in[]: -1 <= x // InputForm
out[]: -1 <= x
in[]: -1 <= x <= 1/2 // InputForm
out[]: -1 <= x <= 1/2`

So far so good, but **the problem is**:

`in[]: -1 <= x < 1/2 // InputForm
out[]: Inequality[-1, LessEqual, x, Less, 1/2]`

**Why this format ?**, why such an `Inequality[]` function shows up ? It looks like a `FullForm` and not `InputForm` !

How to <s>deal</s> prevent with this behavior ? **How to get a more consistent .. < .. < .. format ?**

I tried to workaround and split the Inequality but I do not really want this output...

`` in[]: Reduce`InequalityExpand[-1 <= x < 1/2] // InputForm
out[]: -1 <= x && x < 1/2 ``

I also tried an awful
`in[]: -1 <= x < 1/2 // InputForm /. {Inequality -> List, LessEqual -> "<=", Less -> "<", Greater -> ">", GreaterEqual -> ">="}
out[]: {-1, "<=", x, "<", 1/2}`
But I do not know how to adequately concatenate this list.

NB : InputForm matters for me, I'd like to get this one line output.

Comment: "How to deal with this behavior?" What does it mean to *deal* with it? What is the problem? This feels like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You did not answer my question. What do you want to achieve? InputForm can't be changed, so you're on the wrong track. We can only help you if you explain your actual problem.

Comment: My goal is to remove Inequality[] and replace it with a consistent  .. < .. <= .. format in all cases.

Comment: I'd like to say that the notation  `-1 <= x <= 1/2 ` is not mathematically correct since both `<=` and `<` are binary relations, The mathematically correct notation is `-1 <= x && x < 1/2`.

Comment: Sometimes Mathematica use this notation even if it is both "<" operators `FunctionDomain[Log[4 - x^2], x] // InputForm` gives `Inequality[-2, Less, x, Less, 2]`

Comment: Re your goal: The only way to get a combination of inequality types, `<` and `<=`, is to use `Inequality`. That's a design choice you cannot overcome, I think. Unfortunately, `Inequality[0, Less, x]` evaluates to `Less[0, x]`, so you cannot put all inequalities into a consistent `Inequality[..]` form. (You can expand them, as you point out, but you seem reluctant to deal with that.) I've had to "deal" with this, too, but I don't know if it's the same as your case (see Szabolcs' comments).

Comment: It's not a problem of a combination of inequality types, < and <=, see comment below. I expected to understand why this output and how to prevent it.

Comment: It's very easy to prevent it: don't use `InputForm`. `InputForm` has a purpose and you are clearly trying to use it for something else than what it's meant for yet refusing to explain your problem. I voted to close this question as the problem simply isn't explained in sufficient detail.

Comment: In my opinion, `InputForm` is not `FullForm`, and Mathematica outputs `FullForm` in these cases. For me it's a problem, I cannot give you more details...

Comment: I find the `Inequality` irritating, too, since it's not even documented, but what we think of `InputForm` seems irrelevant to how it actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect) [`Inequality`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inequality) and modify the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) for it:

```
Unprotect[Inequality];
Format[HoldPattern @ Inequality[a__], InputForm] := Module[{res = HoldForm[a], rel},
    rel = List @@ Replace[res[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]],
        {
        Less -> " < ",
        LessEqual -> " <= ",
        Greater -> " > ",
        GreaterEqual -> " >= ",
        Equal -> " == ",
        Unequal -> " != "
        },
        {1}
    ];
    res = InputForm /@ res;
    res[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]] = rel;
    Replace[res, HoldForm[z__] :> OutputForm @ HoldForm @ SequenceForm[z]]
]
Protect[Inequality];
```

The [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm) and `OutputForm @ HoldForm @` bits prevent evaluation leaks, and [`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm) is a special function that behaves like [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) even inside [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm). Example:

```
x < 5 <= y //InputForm
```

> x < 5 <= y

And a version showing that evaluation leaks don't occur:

```
Hold[2+2 < 7 <= 9] //InputForm
```

> Hold[2 + 2 < 7 <= 9]

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[myInputForm];
shortcuts = {
   Less -> " < ",
   LessEqual -> " <= ",
   Greater -> " > ",
   GreaterEqual -> " >= "};
myInputForm[expr_] := Module[{ineqs, i, subs, stripped},
   ineqs = UniqueCases[expr, _Inequality];
   subs = Unique[i] & /@ ineqs;
   stripped = expr /. Thread[ineqs -> subs];
   CellPrint[Cell[
     StringReplace[ToString[stripped, InputForm, PageWidth -> 60],
      Thread[(ToString /@ subs) -> (ineqs /. 
          HoldPattern[Inequality[x__]] :> 
           StringJoin[
            Replace[{x}, Append[shortcuts, e_ :> ToString[e, InputForm]], 1]])]
      ],
     "Output",
     (* This label doesn't work properly: *)
     (* CellLabel ->
         StringJoin["Out[", ToString@$Line, "]//InputForm="] *)
     ]]
   ];

myInputForm[0 < x <= 2 \[Implies] 0 < x^2 <= 4]

(*  Implies[0 < x <= 2, 0 < x^2 <= 4]  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Inequality[-1, LessEqual, x, Less, 1/2] // TraditionalForm

(*   -1<=x<1/2   *)
```

Have fun!